# VB.NET and MySQL : import of another data from table (column) to another table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GCck.png)

I've been having problem importing another data from another table in-order to create a new record of log-in

```
ConnectToDB()
sql = "insert into monitoring (id_num, fname, lname, status, floor_level) VALUES (@num),(@name),(@lname),(@stat),(@lev)"
       
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)

With cmd
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", TextBox3.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", TextBox5.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@lev", lev)

            .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

This is what I tried yet I keep getting a SQL error

and now this is what I kept getting after I fixed my SQL syntax
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnIcI.png) It says An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
Additional information: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 however if I count my database column it is fit and same amount in my query

Comment: the textbox2 is from another code it was automatically filled in after the RFID was scanned

Comment: If only there were some way for us to know what the error message was.

Comment: I suggest that you read a basic SQL tutorial and learn how to write an `INSERT` statement because it's not like that. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_insert.asp) is such a tutorial.

Comment: i i jsut updated the thred and posted an image

Comment: is my insert statement is wrong? okay imma try to look

Comment: @jmcilhinney sire. i use an rfid reader to automatically sift through the database then I  wanted to copy the scanned record into another table inside a database

Comment: sql = "insert into rfidmaintest.monitoring (id_num, fname, lname, status, floor_level) VALUES (@num),(@name),(@lname),(@stat),(@lev)"
           I believe that this is fixed?

Comment: If you have answered your own question, please post an answer and accept it.

Comment: i still havent fix the over all problem. no data has been registerd in my database

Comment: Update your question with all the relevant information, including the current code and the current issue, including the current error message. Error messages are text and should be posted as text, formatted appropriately, not as pictures or links to pictures.

Comment: Good lord! You still haven't fixed your SQL properly. You fixed part of it but ignored the rest. You're obviously not taking the time to read easily accessible information properly. That makes me less inclined to spend my time pointing out the same thing multiple times.

Comment: it's done sir thanks now my last problem is the datestamp

Comment: What datestamp? There's nothing in your question about a datestamp. Your question is not about a datestamp. You need to ask one question at a time and provide all the information relevant to that question. If you now have a new question, create a new question. Don't try to piggyback it onto this one.

Comment: yes im sorry imdone with the question its all working now thank you

Comment: im sorry im not trying to piggyback.... i don't intend to create a new question because I;ve been trying to work it on my end thank you I'm sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Your query for value must be like this

```
sql = "insert into monitoring (id_num, fname, lname, status, floor_level) VALUES (@num, @name, @lname, @stat, @lev)"
```